# Create default user/admin when website initialize - Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm very noob in asp.net area. So my question maybe got answered anywhere in the internet but neither of them I understand the flow creation. Here is the question.

I'm trying to create simple 'Website project', when this site was up, it should creating all necessary identity table inside database if the table not exist yet. Then I'll add up role to the table and set one user as super admin to this table.

Can anyone help me regarding this or share any link regarding this question.

Comment: are you using entity framework?

Comment: I'm just using default framework when creating the project. So there already got login,bootstrap etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a default user account using ASP.NET Idenity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615441/create-a-default-user-account-using-asp-net-idenity)

Comment: @vivek I already look this but it using MVC. Can I using this without MVC?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am assuming you are using ASP.NET MVC.

You can use [Database Initialization](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) to seed your database.

```
public class MyDBInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDBContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDBContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

On the seed method you can populate your database and create a default user for your application.

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDBContext context)
{
    // Initialize default identity roles
    var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
    var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);               
    // RoleTypes is a class containing constant string values for different roles
    List<IdentityRole> identityRoles = new List<IdentityRole>();
    identityRoles.Add(new IdentityRole() { Name = RoleTypes.Admin });
    identityRoles.Add(new IdentityRole() { Name = RoleTypes.Secretary });
    identityRoles.Add(new IdentityRole() { Name = RoleTypes.User });

    foreach(IdentityRole role in identityRoles)
    {
         manager.Create(role);
    }

    // Initialize default user
    var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
    ApplicationUser admin = new ApplicationUser();
    admin.Email = "admin@admin.com";
    admin.UserName = "admin@admin.com";

    manager.Create(admin, "1Admin!");
    manager.AddToRole(admin.Id, RoleTypes.Admin); 

    // Add code to initialize context tables

    base.Seed(context);
}
```

And on your Global.asax.cs you should register your database initializer

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    Database.SetInitializer(new MyDBInitializer());
}
```

Note that there are different types of database initialization strategies whose behavior will depend on your database initializer. Do check the link above.

Comment: I didn't use MVC for this. Can I using this code without MVC?

Comment: @saf21 I assumed you were using MVC it is commonly used with the template. Yes, you can as long as you are using Entity-Framework.

Comment: This will attempt to run every time the application starts, i.e. when IIS is restarted. And it will fail because it won't be able to create second record for "Admin" role. Better add checking if the roles/users exist. Also startup is not the best place for this initialisation - ideally you want it only once, not every time your app starts.

Comment: @trailmax So which part of the web architecture is best to put those function?