# EF CodeFirst with Trusted_Connection=True does not create database

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

Am using EF CodeFirst (Version 6.1.3) with ASP.Net MVC5 / Sql 2014 Express.

It's Entity Framework code first, setup to talk to a local sql server instance using trusted authentication, however database does not get created.

connection string in the Web.config file is

```html
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Ppa" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=PpaOnline;Trusted_Connection=True;" />  
  </connectionStrings>
```

connection string in the App.config file of DAL layer is:

```html
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Ppa" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=PpaOnline;Trusted_Connection=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

DbContext class is:

```
public class Db : DbContext
{
    static Db() 
    {
        var type = typeof(SqlProviderServices);
        if (type == null)
            throw new Exception("Do not remove, ensures static reference to System.Data.Entity.SqlServer");
    }
    public Db() 
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }       

}
```

The PpaOnlineConfiguration class is:

```
public class PpaOnlineConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public PpaOnlineConfiguration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlConnectionFactory("Server=localhost;Database=PpaOnline;Trusted_Connection=True;"));
    }
}
```

Kindly provide input, as to where am I going wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Try using integrated security: `Server=localhost;Database=PpaOnline;Integrated Security=True;`

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/39738064/6138713 where you can utilize [Db Initializer](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Have you changed your local SQL server authentication mode? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017). Of course you'll have to create a migrations in order to get it work after that.

Comment: @ O J Raqueno - I tried with Integrated Security=True; still no success

Comment: Have you tried to connect your server using SQL Management Studio? seems like network issues.

Comment: @Adir, I tried connecting to server using SQL 2014 Management Studio. However am not able to connect to any database in the server now. I did a select * tb_Products (tb_Products is in ShoppingSite_GT db in the same server). I get error "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'tb_Products'.". Tried connecting to other databases gives same error. I followed all steps of changing to windows authentication mode mentioned in the link. Please assist. Thank you

Comment: I can connect to other databases in the server now after restarting the PC! However the PpaOnline database for this project still doesn't get created. Kindly assist. Thank you

Comment: Modifying connection string to following, created the database! <connectionStrings> <add name="Ppa" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" connectionString="Server=ServerName; Database=PpaOnline; Trusted_Connection=Yes; " /> </connectionStrings> Thanks!